Notational issue for exact sequences of abelian groups
In the following short exact sequence of abelian groups $0\rightarrow(\mathbb{Z},n)\rightarrow C(\mathbb{Z},n)\rightarrow(\mathbb{Z},n+1)\rightarrow0$, what does the notation $(\mathbb{Z},n)$ mean? It seems like a direct sum of additive groups, but the notation with $n$ in the second factor is not clear. Any clarification is greatly appreciated!

Where did you come across this notation? I would assume it is explained there somewhere.

Where did you see it? It might be helpful to put some context and perhaps, check out a list of notations / appendix if this is from a book/paper. Personally, I have never seen the notation $C(\Bbb Z,n)$, even if I imagine $(\Bbb Z,n)\equiv\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

It appears on page 23 Exercise2.16 1 of 'Lectures on Algebraic Topology' by Albrecht Dold. I looked at notational conventions and the author doesn't specify the notation.

This is not standard notation.  Odd that it isn't defined in the text.

The notation is defined on page 17, although it's somewhat easy to miss:

If $A$ is an abelian group and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we denote by $(A, k)$ the following graded group: $(A, k)_n$ is $A$ if $n = k$, and is zero for $n \neq k$; i.e. $(A, k)$ is concentrated in dimension $k$, and equals $A$ there.


I missed it.. thanks!
